# Run thread for less than a second

Tags: android

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //code
            }
        }, secondsDelayed * 1000);
```

here even if change value of 1000 to 100 or 10 thread runs for min 1sec.

Comment: For what purpose you need this.

Comment: If you tell us what you're trying to do, we can probably tell you how to do it.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood something... The second argument states that the runable will run AFTER "secondsDelayed * 1000" time elapses and not for the AMOUNT of that time.

Comment: I want to run a method for a specific time

Answer (score 0):

This method postDelayed, has second parameter to let it know , in how much time it should start to run. not for how much time it should run, See Method info below

```
 public final boolean postDelayed (Runnable r, long delayMillis)
  Since: API Level 1
```

Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run after the 
     specified   amount of time elapses. The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached.
Parameters
r   The Runnable that will be executed.
delayMillis     The delay (in milliseconds) until the Runnable will be executed.
Returns

Returns true if the Runnable was successfully placed in to the message queue. Returns false on failure, usually because the looper processing the message queue is exiting. Note that a result of true does not mean the Runnable will be processed -- if the looper is quit before the delivery time of the message occurs then the message will be dropped.

** **Please also include "What you want to do" so one can also provide other possible solutions :)**